# Working with paths and Gulp

Tags: path, terminal, gulp

I'm just getting acquainted with Gulp and although I don't think this is necessarily related to Gulp, I do keep seeing the following paths:

```
'src/**/*.js'
```

What do the asterisk do there exactly?

Also, as I understand it, the following:

```
'./folder'
```

Means, 'this folder' and if that's the case, then why can't I use this instead,

```
'/folder'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gulp uses `node-glob` syntax. You can read the docs for that here: https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob